# Implement the Flash button animation as in iPhone camera in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Im developing a camera app, I want to implement the same animation that happens in default iPhone camera app when you click on the flash button, i.e once you click on the flash button, we can see the other 2 buttons animating, and once you click any one button it again animates and hides.
how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at DDExpandableButton which is able to do exactly this and even includes example code for creating a flash button. https://github.com/ddebin/DDExpandableButton

Comment: Thanks -- I'm glad I was able to answer your question, and welcome to StackOverflow. If you would like to confirm my answer then please click on the tick box to the left of the question.